# SUSE Linux ES 15 SP1 rebooting, how to find out why

Tags: linux, dell-poweredge, sles

I am managing a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP1 system and it will randomly reboot. A few months ago I opened a case with Dell support and we upgraded all firmware available for the system. The system was running fine for 2 months. In the past 2 days the system had gone through a reboot at least once.

In Windows I can look at the Event Viewer to see who rebooted the system, I looked through /var/log/messages and could not find an entry to show who rebooted the system. There is an application vendor logged into the server running SNMP command but I cannot confirm if they are restarting the system.

I check the LifeCycle log and there are no reported issues of the system rebooting due to a hardware issue.

Any suggestions on how I can track who is rebooting the server or why it is reporting?

Comment: **There is an application vendor logged into the server running SNMP command but I cannot confirm if they are restarting the system.** - Have you asked them?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557935/240147